# What will be host value to connect for a Docker application with Docker database?

Tags: spring-boot, docker, dockerfile

Have a Docker database mySql which has been setup like port 3308:3306, that mean internal docker port 3306 has been hosted by local host port 3308 and i am able to connect with this DB from my local machine and application by using port 3308 simply.

but if i run an application in Docker itself, what should be the value of below hostname and port to connect with Docker database.

jdbc:mysql://**hostname**:**port**/DBName?useSSL=false

Comment: I'd suggest reading through [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation, even if you're not using Compose.  Without Compose you can replicate its setup creating a [bridge network](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/) (that documentation is not as approachable, though).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend this kind of setup to the docker run command

- Create a private bridge network.

  ```
  docker network create --driver bridge privet-net
  ```
- Now start your application and DB containers along with the following flag added.

  ```
  --network private-net
  ```

> On user-defined networks, containers can not only communicate by IP address but can also resolve a container name to an IP address. This capability is called automatic service discovery.

Read [this](https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-standalone/) for more details on Docker container networking.

- Now you can use the following URL to access the database.

  ```
  jdbc:mysql://<DB_Container_name>:port/DBName?useSSL=false
  ```

This approach might look complex, but its the recommended way. With this setup, your DB will be in a private network and cannot be accessed by other containers as well. This adds extra security to your database.